# Error finding current time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement this time class to find the current time. I am getting wrong time. Can someone please take a look what am I doing wrong here?

```
import time
import datetime

class Time():
def __init__(self):
    currentTime = time.time()
    totalSeconds = int(currentTime)    
    self.__second = totalSeconds % 60
    totalMinutes = totalSeconds // 60
    self.__minute = totalMinutes %60
    totalHours = totalMinutes// 60
    self.__hour = totalHours % 12

def getSecond(self):
    return self.__second

def getMinute(self):
    return self.__minute

def getHour(self):
    return self.__hour
def main():
    t = Time()
    print("Current Time is : ", t.getHour(), ":", t.getMinute(), ":",   t.getSecond())
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    print(time.ctime())

main()
```

Comment: You reinvented the wheel. The `datetime` module has all the functionality you wrote already.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you get when you run this program, and the output you expected?

Comment: Also the code seems correct. The hour part it gives you is UTC (GMT +0), since time.time() returns time in seconds since epoch. But off course, as others have said, you should use the datetime module as it has all of these.

Comment: The OP is using the datetime module in their code, I imagine this is an exercise.

Comment: @Bikram, it is currently  6:21 utc so your time is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your code always deals with UTC times, but you are comparing the result with time in your time zone. Try this:

```
def main():
    t = Time()
    print("Current Time is : ", t.getHour(), ":", t.getMinute(), ":",   t.getSecond())
    print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().time())
    print(time.asctime(time.gmtime()))
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am trying to get the local time using my Time class. I can not find out how to get seconds since epoch to current local time. basically I want to get the correct first "print" statement in the above code.